# libgdx issues with shapes (triangles)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to create some raindrops in libgdx, as it turns out, rectangles are not that great as raindrops, atleast not when I want them kinda big. Does anyone have an idea in how to make this as triangles?

```
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;

private void spawnRaindrop() {
  Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
  raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800-64);
  raindrop.y = 480;
  raindrop.width = 64;
  raindrop.height = 64;
  raindrops.add(raindrop);
  lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
  raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
  if(raindrop.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
}
```

This code is from 'A-simple-game' from libgdx at github.

It would be great if I could do this with triangles, or if you have a better plan that's fine to!

Edit

If I have this:

```
      float[] vertices = new float[] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,
        0, 0.5f
      };

      triangle = new Polygon();
      triangle.setVertices(vertices);
```

How can see what this looks like on the screen?

Edit 2:

It's fine, I solved it! I managed to fix the vertices using shapeRenderer, and using Intersector for collision controll

Answer (score 0):

To use Triangles in libgdx, check [this simple tutorial](http://www.alcove-games.com/opengl-es-1-x-tutorials/tutorial-01-drawing-your-first-triangle/). Then adapt it to your case.